# the digital signature in the assembly

Tags: .net-assembly, strongname

I read a lot of articles about strong name, then I want to know
where is the digital signature in the assembly?
in the manifest or in the metadata?
thank you advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key is inserted inside the assemblyDef table of the manifest while the digital signature is inserted into a special part of the CLR header.
from the book "Practical .NET2 and C#2"